# python doesn't return value when using special characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I'm trying to run a script to get some data from our Git API but when I try to use the API filter "projects?search=defects" it only returns: {"Git2":[]}. I'm suspecting it may be related to the "?" symbol.

Below is the code which I'm using. The "Git" function works fine, but the "Git2" function doesn't. What I'm doing wrong?

```
import requests
from flask import Flask
import os
import json

uri = "https://gitlab.local.com/api/v4/"

#this code work
@app.route('/git')
def Git():
  uri2 = "projects"
  uri3 = uri + uri2
  response = requests.get(uri3)
  return({"Git" : response.json()})

#this code doesnt work
@app.route('/git2')
def Git2():
  uri2 = "projects?search=my-defects"
  uri3 = uri + uri2
  response = requests.get(uri3)
  return({"Git2" : response.json()})
```

Comment: Are you sure (using Postman, curl, etc.) that the `/projects?search=my-defects` route is returning data?

Comment: Also, take a look at the documentation for passing URL params in the *requests* library. It looks like query params are supposed to be in a separate argument. https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use flask you should consider using custom flask functions.

```
import requests
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import os

uri = "https://gitlab.local.com/api/v4/"

#this code work
@app.route('/git')
def Git():
  uri2 = "projects"
  uri3 = uri + uri2
  response = requests.get(uri3)
  return jsonify({"Git" : response})
```

The requests library takes in query parameters as well, so instead of adding the query parameters directly to your url just add it as an argument to the get request.

```
#this code works too
@app.route('/git2')
def Git2():
  params = {"search":"my-defects"}
  response = requests.get(uri3, params=params)
  return jsonify({"Git2" : response})
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you @maestro-inc the code worked as a charm. I just need add the uri2 uri3 lines before the param  line.